# Update PageURL in the Repository through Descriptive Programming

Tags: qtp

i am new to QTP, i have a question regarding to Descriptive Programming, i want to update the Page url dynamically in the repository of the associated repository, when ever the page loads in the browser.

```
dim url,set_url

With Browser("Browser")
            url=    .GetROProperty("url")
            set_url= "title:='"&url&"'"
            MsgBox set_url
            .Page("title:='"&url&"'").Link("Home")
End With
```

Comment: I don't understand the question, descriptive programming is when you ***don't*** use the object repository (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477519/what-is-descriptive-programming-in-qtp)). What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: hi, forget about that, what i want is this that, i want to set the Page("url:='"&URL&"'") "URL" dynamically in the Page Object, but i am unable to do that. i have updated the code. Please help, it gave some error that page Obj doest supports this

Answer (score 2):

Yes, agree with [Motti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3848/motti/), DP(Descriptive Programming) is alternative to OR (Object Repository). If you are using DP, you do not need to add that object in OR

Comment: hi, forget about that, what i want is this that, i want to set the Page("url:='"&URL&"'") "URL" dynamically in the Page Object, but i am unable to do that. i have updated the code. Please help, it gave some error that page Obj doest supports this

Answer (score 1):

First of all you don't really need the URL to identify the page, a browser only has one `Page` object so using any description will do (e.g. `Page("title:=.*")`)

Looking at your code I see several problems:

1. You have redundant single quotes `'` around the URL.
2. The `title` property isn't very likely to match the URL
3. once you have descriptive programming you can't have a descendent from the object repository so you can't have `Link("Home")` under your page.

You should be using something like:

```
.Page("url:=" & url).Link("href:=.*home.*").Click
```

Comment: i want to make my script unified as i want to test the same scenarios different country languages, in that case the title becomes different(due to language translation) and is not understandable by the QTP, so want i want is to get the URL on run time and set that URL in the page Title.

Comment: While running this, .Page("url:=" & url).Link("href:=.*home.*").Click giving an error that Object doesn't support the property url .Page

Comment: dim url
With Browser("Browser")
   url= .GetROProperty("url")
   .Page("url:=" & url)
   If .Link("Home").Exist Then
    MsgBox "home Link ","Home Link found on the Page"
   End If
End With

Comment: I am doing something like this

Comment: AFAIK `Page` does support **url**, anyway as I said, you don't need to have a description for the page.

Comment: @Zain you can also parametrize the properties in the object repository.

Comment: next question was my that, but i am in a problem, whenever i want to parametrize the page url in repository, it is shown as disabled, how can i enable that?